# Multiline responsive ::before border

Tags: css, responsive

I have to redesign portions of a website for responsive capabilities.

I have a H2 title, with a partial bottom border made with ::before and CSS.
All works well, except on narrow screen when long title are now multiline, the bottom border is then displayed in the middle of everything.

What should I change in the following ? Thank you

```
content: " ";
position: absolute;
top: 35px;
left: 0;
width: 40px;
height: 2px;
background-color: #1f86ef;
```

Comment: Don't use top use bottom : 0

Comment: Also, you may consider using media queries to change the h2 font-size so it doesn't become multi-line.  You can also use [vw units for responsive fonts](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_responsive_text.asp).